# Hide shadow of rating bar

Tags: android, ratingbar

Customizing `RatingBar` shows me shadow

**How to hide this shadow ?**

[image]

```
           <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBarMain"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgThumbFix"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/ratingbar_red_small"
            android:stepSize="1" />
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

set

```
android:layout_height="EQUAL_TO_IMAGE_HEIGHT"
```

example

```
android:layout_height="35dp"
```

Comment: it doesn't work for every mobile screen.. so fixed height is not the proper solution!

Comment: You have to add height to dimens resource; and then you can manage the multiple screen resolution.

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is:

It is repeating the last bit line of the image  if the height of your View is 50 px and the height of image is 40 px, then for rest of the 10 px it will be filled by repeating the last bit of your image.

You have to give the exact height equals to your image height to RatingBar.

```
android:layout_height="40dp"
```

Same problem was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9356898/593709)

Comment: it doesn't work for every mobile screen.. so fixed height is not the proper solution!

Comment: @MayurR.Amipara I agree, in that case you can define the height using dimension for every screen type like hdpi, mdpi etc to exact rating image heights you've in your drawable folders. Here's how you can define dimension, [Storing dimensions in xml file in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3885343/593709)

Comment: Why "sp" instead of "dp"?

Comment: Yes it should be dp.

Answer (score 4):

Another simple solution woud be to leave a row of empty pixels in the star image using an image editor like photoshop. Then the repeated or stretched row of pixels in the ratingbar would be empty. This aproach solved my issue.