# Can someone explain how Android qualifiers works?

Tags: android, resources, ratingbar

I really confused about android qualifiers.

I want to create custom design for `RatingBar`. So I created `rating_bar.xml` file and put it to `drawable` folder. Here is the source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/star_off"/>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress" android:drawable="@drawable/star_on"/>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress" android:drawable="@drawable/star_on"/>
</layer-list>
```

I have star design for xhdpi displays only. I thought that if I put star_on and star_off images to drawable-xhdpi folder than everything will automatically be resized for all different densities (mdpi and hdpi). Yep, it resized, but I got some artifacts for hdpi and mdpi. The same as here: [Android custom RatingBar image artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356799/android-custom-ratingbar-image-artifacts)
I tried solutions that were described there, but nothing helped me. On xhdpi devices I have no artifacts, but on mdpi and hdpi devices there are artifacts.

Then I decided to put star_on and star_off images to drawable-nodpi folder. So I got good result without any artifacts for xhdpi and hdpi screens, but for mdpi screen images were too big.

Then I decided to copy star_on and star_off images to drawable-mdpi folder and reduce images size. It also didn't help.

Then I put big star images to xhdpi and hdpi folders, and small star images to mdpi folder. I thought that if I run my app on mdpi device images from drawable-mdpi will be chosen. But it seems like Android choose images from hdpi or from xhdpi folder and scale them automatically for mdpi screen because I have artifacts again. I also tried to put small images to drawable folder. It also didn't help.

So how Android choose resources? I thought if I have resources шт drawable, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi and drawable-xhdpi than Android try to find resource in folder with same density as device has. And if there are no such resource than it takes from drawable folder.

Answer (score 4):

[This Developers guide part](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch) explains what you exactly need i guess. It demonstrates with an example:

> To demonstrate how Android selects an alternative resource, assume the
>   following drawable directories each contain different versions of the
>   same images:

```
drawable/
drawable-en/
drawable-fr-rCA/
drawable-en-port/
drawable-en-notouch-12key/
drawable-port-ldpi/
drawable-port-notouch-12key/
```

> And assume the following is the device configuration:

```
Locale = en-GB 
Screen orientation = port 
Screen pixel density = hdpi 
Touchscreen type = notouch 
Primary text input method = 12key
```

> By comparing the device configuration to the available alternative
>   resources, Android selects drawables from

**`drawable-en-port`**

There is also a selection diagram describing *how android selects qualifiers.*

Answer (score 2):

android choose resources from drawable folders according to **dpi**

there are four screen densities

1. ldpi
2. mdpi
3. hdpi
4. xhdpi

four screen sizes

```
layout-small
layout-nomal
layout-large
layout-xlarge
```

**small screen size = 2.2" - 2.7" (approx)**

**normal screen size = 3.0" - 4.7" (approx)**

**large screen size = 5" - 7" (approx)**

**xlarge screen size = 7"> (approx)**

**ldpi = 120dpi**

**mdpi = 160dpi**

**hdpi  240dpi**

**xhdpi = 320dpi**

create your avd according to these densities and screen sizes then check the result