# Custom Rating Bar with various screen sizes

Tags: android, android-screen-support, ratingbar

This is very frustating.I have made a custom rating bar with the help of this link: http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/

And now when I look with various screen sizes to check [image]the rating bar..It shows me very strange view.I have to use this rating bar in various hence I can not make layouts for all screen sizes...I have to work with one layout for various screen.

Answer (score 1):

give values in `dp` instead of `dpi`. see the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). I also suggest you to use different images for different devices like `hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi`.

Comment: ok..it works ..but now shadow is still there..for large screen sizes

Comment: shadow of the star..same as in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356799/android-custom-ratingbar-image-artifacts

Comment: firstly thanks for help and yes..I have done all these things related to this problem but could not help..as I am facing it for 2-3 days..and all the answers are only for one screen size..but when these solution check with various screen sizes it is creating problem same as I am facing ....