# How to change android rating Bar stars?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-bitmap, ratingbar

I am trying to change the stars of my rating bar by creating new style, this what i did :

```
<style name="RatingBarSmall" parent="android:Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.RatingBar.Indicator">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/rating_bar</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">36dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">36dp</item>
    </style>
```

drawable/rating_bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/rating_star_empty" />
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/rating_star_empty" />
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/rating_star_filled" />
</layer-list>
```

rating bar xml view:

```
<RatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
                    style="@style/RatingBarSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:isIndicator="true"
                    android:rating="5" />
```

and here is the tow images:

[image: rating_star_empty]
[image: rating_star_filled]

but i don't know why i got vertical lines under the stars as you can see int the bellow picture:
[image]

EDIT: SOLVED:i just set the rating bar height as the image height.

thanks

Comment: You might want to use wrap_content instead of minHeight and maxheight

Comment: You can compare your code with [this](http://www.geeks.gallery/how-to-code-custom-ratingbar-in-android/). May be that can help you.

Comment: This might be bug in Rating bar. I face same issue many time but with no desired result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android custom RatingBar image artifacts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356799/android-custom-ratingbar-image-artifacts)

Comment: Use a FrameLayout for this; I had the same problem before! Let me know if you more help

Comment: @Eenvincible thank you for your response. do you mean to wrap the rating bar with frameLayout ? i did that but same result.

Comment: @AjitPratapSingh thank you for your comment. i have edit the question . you could see that i am using wrap content. same result .

Comment: @activesince93 thank you, i will do and let you know if that helps.

Comment: @GopalSinghSirvi thank you for you reply. i set a height but that just cut a part of the lines.

Comment: Try giving height in `pixels` rather that `dp`.

Comment: thank you all for you help and time. finally i just give the rating bar a height that equal to the star image height (in dp). and that's solved the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I observe this problem in this way. You may create any values in `res/values/dimens.xml` for each screen (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi) like:

```
<dimen name="rating_min_height">36dp</dimen>
<dimen name="rating_min_width">36dp</dimen>
```

And use this:

```
<style name="RatingBarSmall" parent="android:Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.RatingBar.Indicator">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/rating_bar</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/rating_min_height</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">@dimen/rating_min_width</item>
</style>
```

Or you can apply that logic to your drawable (`rating_star_empty` and `rating_star_filled`)

Comment: `<dimen name="raiting_min_weight">36dp</dimen>` I guess you mean `<dimen name="raiting_min_width">36dp</dimen>`